# ADD Listener to textfield in javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to get the equivalent code for the following code in javafx (plzzz explain it also)

```
textfield.addActionListener(
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    System.out.println(event.getActionCommand();)`
```

`

Comment: Just include invalid syntax in your code. Any invalid syntax. This will have the same effect as the above code. Otherwise we need a better description of what you're trying to do...

Comment: I want to show the message on the console written in the textfield when I press enter key while writing in textfield . I found above code in newboston site.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
textfield.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Obverride
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
         System.out.println(textfield.getText());
    }
});
```

or using a lambda expression

```
textfield.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println(textfield.getText()));
```

Since the above code seems like Swing code, be sure to use the correct JavaFX classes, i.e.

```
javafx.event.ActionEvent
javafx.event.EventHandler
javafx.scene.control.TextField
```